# How to order print data in a loop from PHP?

Tags: php

The point is that in the variable or condition `$DivCol` it shows me the two old results while it `$DivColGrid` shows me the rest of the most recent results, let's say suppose that I have 5 registered products, to always show the most recent products the condition is passed to `SQL/MYSQL-> DESC` so the product `1, 2` is shown in `$DivCol` while it `3, 4, 5` is shown in `$DivColGrid`.

In conclusion what I want is to show the most recent products added but starting from `$DivCol`, that is, it `$DivCol` must contain the products `5, 4` while `3, 2, 1` in `$DivColGrid`.

```
$DivCol = '<div class="col-1">';
$DivColGrid = '<div class="col-grid">';
$i=1;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    if ($i%2 == 0) {
        $DivCol .= '<div class="post">
                        '.$mini_title.'
                    </div>';
        $first = false;
    } else {
        $DivColGrid .= '<div class="post">
                        '.$mini_title.'
                    </div>';
    }

    $i++;

}
$DivColGrid .= '</div>';
$DivCol .= '</div>';

echo $DivCol.$DivColGrid;
```

Comment: How do you know what is old vs what is new? Also, the code you show is (1) not enough to reproduce (2) simply does an even/odd row selection.

Comment: @sal because already in the mysql query I already pass the DESC condition but I need to sort it inside the loop

Comment: @sal here `if ($i%2 == 0)` what I do is show two articles in a different container, that is, it is a different design, therefore this condition

Comment: @sal All I want is to show product 5 and 4 here `$DivCol` and the rest of the products here `$DivColGrid` in this case would be 3, 2, 1.

Comment: It's unclear why you need to sort inside the loop, if you already have them sorted from the query. Can you show the actual output and what the actual desired output is?

Comment: Ok. Then the question is: can you have 10 products? If yes, then how do you decide?

Comment: @sal Because in the container where I only show two articles, the design is very different from the other, it is a larger cover design, so it is not good that older products are displayed there but the most recent, because the forum is a sports newspaper not I know if you understand me.

Comment: @sal I have more conditions to control if there are 10 or more products: `echo Main($con, $language, $active, $main_cover='featured_news', $limit='5');` but since that does not imply the order that I want, so I do not add this code, because the order of the result must be within the loop applying some parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, you have 5 products returned by the SQL query, already sorted in reverse order (how you want them), and now all you want is to pick the first two from the sorted list and put them inside the first div-container, and the rest in the other. If that is all correct, then this should suffice:

```
$DivCol = '<div class="col-1">';
$DivColGrid = '<div class="col-grid">';
$i=1;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    if ($i <= 2) {  // essentially, only pick the first two
        $DivCol .= '<div class="post">
                        '.$mini_title.'
                    </div>';
        $first = false;
    } else {
        $DivColGrid .= '<div class="post">
                        '.$mini_title.'
                    </div>';
    }

    $i++;

}
$DivColGrid .= '</div>';
$DivCol .= '</div>';

echo $DivCol.$DivColGrid;
```